# How to combine two parsers in Haskell ReadP anonymously?

Tags: parsing, haskell, parser-combinators

### The Problem

I want to chain two `ReadP` parsers anonymously.

### Example

Input characters are in `{'a', 'o', '+', ' '}` where `' '` is a space.
I want to parse this input according to the following rules:

- the first o or a is not preceeded by a space/plus
- every other o is preceeded by a space
- every other a is preceeded by a plus

### The BNF

In case this is not clear, I came up with the following BNF:

```
{-
  <Input> :: = <O> <Expr> | <A> <Expr>
  <Expr> ::= <Space> <O> <Expr> | <Plus> <A> <Expr> | <EOL>
  <O> ::= "o"
  <A> ::= "a"
  <Space> ::= " "
  <Plus> ::= "+"
-}
```

### Specific questions

The idea is, that the rules "o preceeded by space" and "a preceeded by plus"
(if not at the beginning) should not be part of the o or a parser, nor do
I want to create an explicit/named parser, because that is a part of the
definition of an expression (`Expr`).

**How do I chain the `oParser` with the `spaceParser`?**

- Composition (does not work): `spaceParser . oParser`
- `(+++)` is the symmetric choice: `oParser (+++) spaceParser`. And related to that: Is `(+++)` equivalent to `<|>` from `Control.Applicative`?
- `ReadP.choice [oParser, spaceParser]` creates a new parser, which obviously does not work for a string, but I did that previously and the behaviour of `choice` surprised me. How does `choice` work?

### The Code

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
module Parser (main) where
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- modules
import Text.ParserCombinators.ReadP as ReadP
import Data.Char as D
import Control.Applicative
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- this parses one o
oParser :: ReadP Char
oParser = satisfy (== 'o')

-- this parses one a
aParser :: ReadP Char
aParser = satisfy (== 'a') --(\v -> v == 'a')

-- this parses one plus
pParser :: ReadP Char
pParser = satisfy (== '+')

spaceParser :: ReadP Char
spaceParser = satisfy D.isSpace    

parseExpr :: ReadP String
parseExpr = -- ReadP.choice [oParser, spaceParser]

main :: IO ()
main = print [ x | (x, "") <- ReadP.readP_to_S parseExpr  "o +a o+a+a o o"]
```

Thank you **a lot** for reading all of that :) (And: Which haskell parsing libraries would you recommend?)

Comment: I would recommend [megaparsec](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/megaparsec).

Comment: Why? Edit: Woooow, nice! :D Related to that: How do you find packages like that? There is [this list](https://hackage.haskell.org/packages/#cat:Parsing) but can you sort hackage packages by popularity?

Comment: No you can't. I guess you [ask](https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/x4g18/the_mustknow_list_of_packages_on_hackage/) or know the topics or read the blogs/lists. [Sort by download](https://hackage.haskell.org/packages/top) is close.

Comment: I wholeheartedly back up the recommendation of `megaparsec`. There, as here, one sequences parsers using their `Monad` or `Applicative` instances. You are looking for the `spaceParser  *> oParser` and `spaceParser  *> aParser` parsers.